# Is there is an equivalent of Jpanel in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

Hi I am using GWT and I want to create a new panel whenever a button is clicked. Which widget in GWT will help me to create a new panel like that of Java's Jpanel?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Panel.html please look at "Direct Known Subclasses". You can add any, don't forget to add your panel to RootPanel or to a panel which is already visible.